# If I upgrade to lion, will FCS 2 still work?

Tags: macos, final-cut-pro

I've noticed that a lot of different people have been asking, "If I upgrade to lion, will *this* program work?". So I guess lion isn't very compatible? Here's my question: Will FCS 2 work with lion? FCS 2 includes:

- Final Cut Pro 6
- Motion 3
- Color 1
- Soundtrack Pro 3
- DVD Studio Pro 3
- Compressor 3

Don't tell me to upgrade to Final Cut X; It is junk compared to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Final Cut Studio 2 will *run* on Lion, but will not *install* on Lion. Apparently, the installer program requires Rosetta, but the software itself does not. So yes, it should work, *if* it never needs reinstallation, but if it does, you're stuck. Proceed with caution.

Sources:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3134652?start=0&tstart=0
- personal experimentation

Comment: wtf this is sad apple fail